# Full page background on Magento 2 page

Tags: magento2, theme, design

I'm trying to understand, how could I implement a full page background on a custom theme.
For example if I want to manually create a slider inside a Magento 2 home page like this:
[image]

How could I do?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS if you need to break an element out of it's container.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100vw
```

This will make the element the side of the viewport, you can then position the element to ensure it's completely in the centre.

Comment: if you manipulate css on a specific section of magento2, you will mess up al block that comes later, and all blocks.
This is okey just when you have got a single html/css page because in magento you have to link different phmtl with lots of xml files.

Comment: You can target whatever element you like with CSS, there is nothing to force you to affect other blocks

Answer (score 0):

you can use container "page.top" and move/add you element inside this container like below

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home.banner">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_banner_section</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
 
    <body/>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi there, this way could be okey but then how can i move the image under the top menu?

Comment: Now the html is: <main div> <div page-header> <div banner>... the banner has got the image but now the banner should start from the top page and then the page header should be insider the banner.

Comment: @Francesco You can try this css

.page-header {
position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}